# how i can Search word in xpath and return the wanted WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using `java` `selenium` to check a site.

I want to check if a button is exist in every page (there are a lot pages that have that button named `Bar`).

I'v tried to find that element in many ways, just the `xpath` have been worked.

by the `xpath` I can just check specific button.

[image]

This is my code :

```
     WebElement BarChart = (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div/ng-view/div/div[2][contains(text(), 'Bar')]"));
```

This is not work.
How I can find this element(Bar button) by the word `"Bar"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find your button on all of pages you should use relative `XPath` instead of absolute as `HTML` tree could be different on each page. So try this one:

```
//button[contains(text(), "Bar")]
```

Comment: Hi,
Now i'm facing another similar problem But with input box(not button).
This is an input date box.
My code:
                                   ListBar = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(text(), 'dd.MM.yyyy')]")); 

This in not working. 

 

How i can find this element?

Comment: Show `HTML` for input box

Comment: <input required="required" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-valid-required ng-touched" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-change="updateDate(dt)" type="text">

Comment: Hmm... Regarding provided code sample I can't see whether this input element has any text at all... try `//input[@datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"]`